# Play music stream via node

Tags: audio, streaming

Is there anyway for me to play a music stream (google play music, I already got the streamURL) in the raspberry pi via node? (and also, output it to audio port).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nodejs, try using the [nodejs groove module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/groove) which supports network streams and playback control. This module contains native code which requires `libgroove`.

To install libgroove for raspbian, I have followed the following guide and succeeded: [Turn Your Raspberry Pi Into a Music Player Server](http://andrewkelley.me/post/raspberry-pi-music-player-server.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use Simon Weber's [gmusicapi](http://unofficial-google-music-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) python library to access Google Play Music

First install gmusicapi and mplayer

```
pip install gmusicapi
apt-get install mplayer
```

Then use my sample code. Any comments are welcome. I couldn't solve the 'device_id' problem in Mobileclient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Plays random song from Google Play Music Library
# Requirements : 
# gmusicapi - http://unofficial-google-music-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
# mplayer   - 

from gmusicapi import Mobileclient
from gmusicapi import Webclient
import subprocess
from random import randint

api = Mobileclient()
api.login('user@gmail.com', 'gmail_password')

api1 = Webclient()
api1.login('user@gmail.com', 'gmail_password')

devices = api1.get_registered_devices()
device_id = (devices[1]['id']).replace("0x","")

library = api.get_all_songs()

num = randint(1, len(library))

song_id = library[num]["id"]
song_url = api.get_stream_url(song_id,device_id)

api.logout()
api1.logout()

subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/mplayer", song_url])
```